# Python's equivalence of Typescript's indexable type?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In typescript, there is a construct called index signature that let me, for instance, express that all properties of a particular object have values of type string, i.e:

```js
type Foo = { [key: string]: string }
```

How do I type hint something similar in Python, e.g express that all attributes of a class should have values of type string? The reason I want to do this because I have a Python class whose attributes are not known in advance, but are set dynamically.

Comment: You can't really do static type checking with dynamically added attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your `Foo` type would be a `dict` with keys and values that both have type `str`:

```
Foo = dict[str, str]
```

If you're generating attributes on a custom class dynamically via `__getattr__`, the signature of `__getattr__` determines the type of the attributes:

```
class Foo:
    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> str:
        return "foo"

f = Foo()
reveal_type(f.bar)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
```

Comment: Might need to show an MRE to better illustrate what you're working with.  In general, though, the type of an object's attributes is set in its `__init__`.  Maybe the fix is just to move all the initialization into there?  Impossible to say without seeing any code.

Comment: The class does indeed use __getattr__, so your method probably works. I will test it tomorrow though as it is late. But thanks in advance !